# Magento 2 add wishlist in add to cart block

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hi I used reference container on catalog_product_view.xml but it shows just on configurable products. I add another one without additional and just shows on simple products. Also used move command but still can't see in both simple and configurable product. What should I do? I am using Magento 2.1.8

```
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved by below instruction:

Add

```
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
       <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml" before="-"/>
   </referenceBlock>
```

to "catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml"

and

```
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
               <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml" before="-"/>
   </referenceBlock>
```

to "catalog_product_view.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the block name `product.info.addtocart.additional` and `product.info.addtocart` work as expected for configurable products and simple products respectively.

Since you can't see the block yourself, you have likely some customisations, or custom theme that changes the way magento product layout works.

To debug this, my suggestion may be:

- look at the log for possible errors
- find in your `app/code` folder and `app/design/frontend` folder the word `addto.phtml`; This name is the template name and it should be showing you where in your system you have some customisations changing the behaviour of this template? of course find the word `product.info.addtocart` in these folders will be useful too
- then more deeper, in the function `\Magento\Framework\View\Layout::generateXml`, add the line (temporarily) `$xml->asXML();die();` and then view source will show you all the blocks in your page

--> to do this last step, if you are worry to change the core or find it geek to look at the layout from view source, you may either use Magento debbuging tool to show you all the blocks (although it will be limited for your case as your block does not appear) and then I find the [plugin](https://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-3) from Alan Storm quite useful in these cases..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me

Comment: ok, how about flushing the cache, sometimes easy tricks are the ones we can forget..